# unable to inherit a parent class with no default constructor

Tags: java

I have few different entities each of which derive from AbstractXYZEntity. All entities belong to XYZ domain and their XYZId is of type Long.

I want to create a datatype `class XYZId extends Long` and each entity will then look like below -

```
public class XYZEntityOne extends AbstractXYZEntity {
  XYZId entityOneId;
}
```

Problem is when I try to create XYZId, compiler shows me following error -

> There is no default constructor available in java.lang.Long

I understand that default constructor is not available in Long as it doesn't hold any meaning. One has to have some number before one creates an instance of Long.

But then why can't I create a datatype extending from it which too doesn't have a default constructor?

Comment: [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) is declared "final". you cannot extend it.

Comment: @Aominè Oh, I got it. Super thanks. But then is there a way to create a create a superficial datatype name over Long?

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, there's no implicit constructor inheritance. If you don't explicitly call the parent's constructor using the `super` keyword, it's assumed you're invoking its default constructor (i.e., same as calling `super()` with no arguments), which would, of course, fail if the parent class does not have a default constructor. E.g.:

```
public class Parent {
    // Note: No default constructor

    public Parent(String s) {
        // Do something with s
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
}
```

This is somewhat of a moot discussion in this case, though, since `java.lang.Long` is `final`, and you can't extend it anyway. Instead, you could create an `XYZId` class the **contains** a `long` data member.